# Issues with using Xorg in docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker, xorg

I installed Xorg inside of my docker container, and I am unable to get it running at all. When I launch Xorg from command line I get the error:

```
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (No such file or directory)
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I tried applying the solutions suggested [here](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/3339) but it didn't work for me.

I am currently running Ubuntu 18.04 on a remote GPU *(with X11forwarding enabled)*. Really appreciate if anyone could point out the issue over here.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to run a GUI app within your container? Then you don't need the X server in the container, but on the host.

Comment: @PMF I am trying to run this python package called AI2Thor which requires Graphical interface, it is [here](https://github.com/allenai/ai2thor). The command executed is sudo ai2thor-xorg start, can I clarify by host do you mean the main OS on the remote GPU? If yes then my X server is indeed on the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that package, but the XOrg package is the X *server*, this won't run inside a container, because there's no real display attached. You need to get X-Forwarding from your container to your host running.

For starting, try running `xeyes` (from the x11-apps package) in your container, if it works and you get a pair of eyes on your desktop, that part is ok, if you get an error such as "couldn't connect to Display" you need to set up X forwarding first. You'll find many tutorials on how to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will go and try that out